# Use function in dynamically loaded script

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically/lazy loading in a script with JQuery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "interaction.js",
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true
}).done(function() {
        $.cookie("cookie_name", "value", { expires: 7 });
});
```

Within this script I am try to use a function that already exists and is defined in the main js file:

```
function scrollUp(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 649) {
         $('html, body').scrollTop( $("#christmas-game-wrapper").offset().top); 
    }
}

scrollUp();
```

But when it's called in the lazy loaded script I get:

```
ReferenceError: scrollUp is not defined
```

Is there a way I can use it in the lazy loaded script?

Thanks.

Comment: `scrollUp();` is calling the function BEFORE the actual definition has been parsed. it should be `function scrollUp() { ...} scrollUp();`

Comment: hi yes i was just showing how it was defined and how it is called